# How do I provide partial method as an optional Action

Tags: c#, code-generation, partial-methods

I am migrating some code and have nicely formatted Look-up Tables but they have to be converted into archaic structures for use because of backward compatibility.

I have a GetLookupTable() method which goes and gets a list of SelectItemList, all off my models and lookup calls are code generated but I need to manually alter some of the return SelectItem's so I have implemented a Visitor Pattern that the developer can implement if they wish.

The visitor is done as a Partial Method and if developer wants to implement they can, but I'm getting an error as shown below

> Error  132 Cannot create delegate from method 'InfoChoice.Web.Admin.ViewModels.Product.ProductCreditCardViewModel.LookupTableViewModel.CardTypeVisit(System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem)' because it is a partial method without an implementing declaration

Here is the calling code using Razor

```
<div class='row'>
    <label>Card Type</label>
    @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.CardType, @Model.LookupTable.CardType)
    David Says: @Model.CardType
</div>
```

Here is a stripped down Model

```
// Generated model
public partial class ProductCreditCardViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Account - Card Type")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string CardType { get; set; }


    // ***************************************************************************************************
    // Lookup Table calls for this model (Generated)
    // ***************************************************************************************************
    public partial class LookupTableViewModel : BaseLookupTableViewModel
    {
        partial void CardTypeVisit(SelectListItem item);

        public SelectList CardType
        {
            get
            {
                return GetLookupItems("ProductCreditCardCardType", CardTypeVisit);
            }
        }
    }

}

public partial class ProductCreditCardViewModel
{
    // Custom Implementation Goes Here
    public partial class LookupTableViewModel : BaseLookupTableViewModel
    {
        //partial void CardTypeVisit(SelectListItem item)
        //{
        //    item.Value = "|" + item.Value + "|";
        //}
    }
}
```

Base LookupTable view model that will return Select Item List data

```
public class BaseLookupTableViewModel
{
    public SelectList GetLookupItems(string lookupName)
    {
        return GetLookupItems(lookupName, "Name", "Text", null, null);
    }
    public SelectList GetLookupItems(string lookupName, Action<SelectListItem> itemVisitor)
    {
        return GetLookupItems(lookupName, "Name", "Text", null, itemVisitor);
    }
    public SelectList GetLookupItems(string lookupName, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, object selectedValue, Action<SelectListItem> itemVisitor)
    {
        // Go get some data from DataStore
        var list = App.Data.Lookup.GetLookupList(lookupName);

        // Convert to IEnumerable<SelectItemList>
        var result = new SelectList(list, dataValueField, dataTextField, selectedValue);

        // If developer would like to alter that list before it is returned, then developer should implement an item visitor
        if (itemVisitor != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                itemVisitor(item);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void SampleVisitor(SelectListItem item)
    {
        item.Value = "Modified: " + item.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct; partial methods **do not exist** if not implemented, so you can't bind a delegate to them in quite that way. Your best option here is either to call it manually based perhaps on a switch (or similar), or if you ***really need*** a delegate, look for the method with reflection (remembering to specify non-public binding-flags) and use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` if the method turns out to exist. Or a lazy option:

```
private void OnCardTypeVisit(SelectListItem item) { CardTypeVisit(item); }
partial void CardTypeVisit(SelectListItem item);
```

now bind your delegate to `OnCardTypeVisit` instead of `CardTypeVisit`.

In terms of delegates, this could also be as simple as changing it to an indirect delegate, which is very similar to the `On*` approach:

```
return GetLookupItems("ProductCreditCardCardType", x => CardTypeVisit(x));
```

(however, if that is an *expression* rather than a *delegate* I would expect failure)

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for: return GetLookupItems("ProductCreditCardCardType", x => CardTypeVisit(x));

Comment: foreach (var item in result)
    {
        // This visitor will does the following: item.Value = "|" + item.Value + "|";
        itemVisitor(item);
        LogUtil.Info(item.Value);
    }
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        LogUtil.Info(item.Value);
    }
This code does not update result. i.e. in the 1st Loop I get the following (|Visa|, |Mastercard|, |AMEX|), but in the second loop I get (Visa, Mastercard, AMEX). I would have thought item was a reference type and would update against the SelectItemList, but it seems to be a copy.